# Cropping map to border of shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export

I am new to QGIS.

I have a number of layers in QGIS, all ot them covering different areas (some Germany only, some Europe etc). I want to export a map as a picture that uses the (German) border of the shapefile, essentially cropping away everything outside of German border.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the map you want to export in vector or raster format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the shape of Germany to a new layer, set layer rendering to `Inverted Polygons` and apply a style.

*Screenshot: here the style is set to a semi-transparent red for visualization purpose. You could set a white, opaque style:*
[image]